# How can I hang a framed picture onto a wallpapered concrete wall without damaging the wall surface?

Tags: walls, concrete, hanging

I have a framed picture about two feet by three feet in size that weighs about one pound (not a sheet of paper). I want to hang it onto a wall that is of full-blown hard concrete and covered with paper wallpaper (not vinyl - just paper).

The default way would be to drill the concrete and insert an anchor but that would damage the wall surface.

Is there a way to hang such picture onto such wall without damaging the wall?

Comment: Setup a little stand so it does not hang on the wall but on the stand.

Comment: Cf. https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/2316/1869

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would be tempted to try those removable  stick up hangers from 3M. They come in different sizes for different weights. They don't penetrate or leave a stain when you remove them.

[image]

Comment: I have had the fail leading to a broken frame, and removeing plaster by the force the the other one was pulled of with.   I still like them for when renting, as having to "make good" on hole when we moved out was a lot better then 10!

Comment: My weapon of choice in these circumstances.  Just be sure to do an effective cleaning job per the instructions prior to installing.

Comment: nice pic edit Tester

Comment: I used these to mount a surveillance camera underneath a shelf.  Worked like a charm.

Comment: I have used these literally thousands of times professionally. They work extremely well, as long as you follow their recommendations. Make sure the surface is clean and dry, and—most importantly—use the proper weight rated hooks. Don't put a 5 pound picture on a 2 pound hook, and you'll be fine. Removing them is a piece of cake, but you have to 'stretch' them to release, not 'peel' them off the wall. Peeling will cause wall damage.